# Add more behavior to existing onclick attribute in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

how can i add more behaviour to existing onclick events e.g.
if the existing object looks like

```
<a href="http://abc" onclick="sayHello()">link</a>
<script>
function sayHello(){
    alert('hello');
}

function sayGoodMorning(){
    alert('Good Morning');
}
</script>
```

how can i add more behavior to the onclick that would do also the following

```
alert("say hello again");
sayGoodMorning()
```

Best Regards,
Keshav

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's the dirtiest way :)

```
<a href=".." onclick='sayHello();alert("say hello again");sayGoodMorning()'>.</a>
```

Here's a somewhat saner version. Wrap everything into a function:

```
<a href=".." onclick="sayItAll()">..</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
function sayItAll() {
    sayHello();
    alert("say hello again");
    sayGoodMorning();
}
```

And here's the proper way to do it. Use the event registration model instead of relying on the `onclick` attribute or property.

```
<a id="linkId" href="...">some link</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
var link = document.getElementById("linkId");
addEvent(link, "click", sayHello);
addEvent(link, "click", function() {
    alert("say hello again");
});
addEvent(link, "click", sayGoodMorning);
```

A cross-browser implementation of the `addEvent` function is given below (from [scottandrew.com](http://www.scottandrew.com/weblog/articles/cbs-events)):

```
function addEvent(obj, evType, fn) {
    if (obj.addEventListener) {
        obj.addEventListener(evType, fn, false);
        return true;
    } else if (obj.attachEvent) {
        var r = obj.attachEvent("on" + evType, fn);
        return r;
    } else {
        alert("Handler could not be attached");
    }
}
```

Note that if all 3 actions must be run sequentially, then you should still go ahead and wrap them in a single function. But this approach still tops the second approach, although it seems a little verbose.

```
var link = document.getElementById("linkId");
addEvent(link, "click", function() {
    sayHello();
    alert("say hello again");
    sayGoodMorning();
});
```

Comment: +1 - the only thing I would change would be to remove the `useCapture` from the `addEvent` implementation to keep consistency across all browsers

Comment: Hi Anurag,
i wanted to add the new behavior with javascript i.e. to get the existing script for onclick event and attach more behavior to it.

i could have added multiple onclick listeners but IE only has attachEvent and it does not support addEvent or addEventListeners which could have been used to add multiple event listeners

Comment: @keshav - the `addEvent` function in the answer is cross-browser and should take care of IE/other browsers.

Comment: @Anurag - yes but the attachEvent overwrites my existing script for onclick what i want to do is really to extend or to say add more event handlers for same event type. 
russ has proposed a solution below to achieve it using anonymous functions.

Comment: @keshav - are you **sure** `attachEvent` overwrites the `onclick` that is added inline in html?

Comment: @Anurag: i tried some sample script http://jsfiddle.net/z3yjh/6/
and yes you are right attachEvent appends to the old script. somehow when i tried some samples b4 posting the question i was not able to get both of them working and thought that attachEvent clears the oldscript.
thanks for explanation and quick comments :)

Comment: Is the addEvent Function compatible with a primeui element and event? I can't make it work... `addEvent( $('#myDropdownId') , "puidropdownchange", myFunc );`

Answer (score 6):

Another way not mentioned is to capture the function currently assigned to the `element.onclick` attribute, then assign a new function that wraps the old one. A simple implementation to demonstrate would be something like

```
function addEvent(element, type, fn) {
    var old = element['on' + type] || function() {};
    element['on' + type] = function () { old(); fn(); };
}

var a = document.getElementById('a');

function sayHello(){
    alert('hello');
}

function sayGoodMorning(){
    alert('Good Morning');
}

addEvent(a, 'click', sayHello);
addEvent(a, 'click', sayGoodMorning);
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PQqm9/)** here

Comment: thanks, this was what i needed(to extend the existing behaviour with javascript, the addevent method above does it very well) also very  thanks for introducing me to jsfiddle looks like a great debugging and sharing tool

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to write a third function:

```
<a href="http://abc" onclick="foo()">link</a>
<script>
function sayHello(){
    alert('hello');
}

function sayGoodMorning(){
    alert('Good Morning');
}

function foo() {
    alert("say hello again");
    sayGoodMorning();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<a href="http://abc" onclick="sayHello(),sayX(),sayY(),sayZ()">link</a>`

would also work

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a slight change to your code:

```
<a href="http://abc" id="a1" onclick="sayHello()">link</a>
```

In plain ol' JavaScript, you'd do something like this.

```
var a = document.getElementById('a1');
a.onclick = function () { alert('say hello again'); a.onclick(); }
```

It's worth noting that jQuery makes this a bit easier. See the documentation on the [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/), [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/), and [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/), for example, and in general the section on [event handler attachment](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-handler-attachment/).

Comment: Be careful ! You'll fall in an infinite loop : you call a.onclick() that calls a.onclick() itself ;)